# Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError when trying to get message by Id. Microsoft Graph GraphServiceClient

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-mail

When I try to download an email from a shared mailbox using the GraphServiceClient I keep getting
Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.
The OData request is not supported.
I've googled the issue and haven't gotten a usable solution.

Originally started with app permission Mail.ReadWrite.  From there added Mail.Read, Mail.ReadBasic,Mail.ReadBasic.All to see if anything would work.  Below is a sample of the code that I'm using.

```
ClientSecretCredential? _clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(_settings.TenantId, _settings.ClientId, _settings.ClientSecret);
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(_clientSecretCredential,new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
var messages = await graphServiceClient.Users["email@account.com"].MailFolders["inbox"].Messages.GetAsync(); 
//messages returns 3 emails  
foreach (var message in messages.Value)
{
    //this throws the error---------------------------------------
    var messageStream = await graphServiceClient
                  .Users["email@account.com"]
                  .MailFolders["inbox"]
                  .Messages[message.Id]
                  .Content
                  .GetAsync();
       //---------------------------------------------------------------
    string path = "File_Path.eml";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        messageStream.CopyTo(fs);
    }
}
```

If there is any gotcha's as far as Azure configurations you can think of that would be appreciated.

**Update**:
As per the answer below, removing  .MailFolders["inbox"] from the message request and adding in TokenCredentialOptions fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I had tried as per the requirement, and I also faced the same error which you get.

[image]

- Then, I updated the code please check below.

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace GraphApp
{
    class MSGraph
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var tenantId = "tenant_Id";
            var clientId = "client_Id";
            var clientSecret = "client_Secret";
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

            try
            {
                var message = await graphClient.Users["User_UPN"]
                    .MailFolders["inbox"]
                    .Messages["message_ID"]
                    .GetAsync();

                var mimeContentStream = await graphClient.Users["User_ID"]
                    .Messages[message.Id]
                    .Content
                    .GetAsync();

                using (var fileStream = File.Create("C:\\Users\\xxxxxxx\\Desktop\\web1\\lastemail.eml"))
                {
                    mimeContentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    await mimeContentStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Email message downloaded successfully.");
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error accessing the Graph API: {ex.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- When I executed the above code the **.eml** file download successful to the given path below

[image]

**References:**

- Referred from Glen Scales - [How to Download a Mail | Graph API | C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1025116/how-to-download-a-mail-graph-api-c).

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  Removing the  .MailFolders["inbox"] from the message download and adding the options was the trick.  Much appreciated